# Why do i keep getting just a JSON array list when refreshing page?

Tags: ajax, laravel, get, vue.js, axios

I am currently building an application using Vue js on top of laravel. I am using so far mostly Vue components on that are mounted on a blade view.

Here's the problem: I am currently trying to send an Ajax GET request to the server to return all records for events in my database using Laravel's eloquet model. I am getting the data and returning it back to my Vue js component no problem but whenever i refresh the page all i see is a json view witht he data and not my component :s

I am going crazy since i can't seem to find the problem.

Route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
//Dashboard routes
Route::get('/admin/events', 'EventsController@index');
Route::post('/user/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@store');
Route::post('/admin/events/create-event', 'EventsController@store');
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $events = Event::all();
    return response()->json($events);
}
```

Events.vue:

```
mount()
{
  axios.get('/admin/events')
  .then(response => {
     this.events = response.data;
   })
   .catch(error =>  {
    this.message = "getData - I get null";
   })
},
```

Please, if anyone knows what is going on PLESASE let me know! :)

Comment: Which route does get data with Ajax and renders the events? / or /home?

Comment: Route::get('/admin/events', 'EventsController@index');

Comment: I am kinda new to this so let me know if ytou need more than that :p Thats the route i use to make the call to my controller

Comment: So this is happening when you're on the home page and clicking refresh? If yes then can you post the HomeControlle, index function